# Perl installation on Debian vs CentOS with Makefile.PL error

Tags: linux, perl, centos, debian, package

I am trying to figure out how to install the proper Debian packages for Perl. I am getting a make error of:

```
Failed to read the configuration: Bad file descriptor at Makefile.PL line 8.
```

My Makefile.PL file contain the following line up to line 9:

```
use 5.008000;
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;

# Read the parameters from Triceps Makefiles 
delete $ENV{MAKEFLAGS}; # these cause spurious messages from make
delete $ENV{MAKELEVEL};
my $TRICEPS_CONF = `make --quiet -f ../../cpp/Makefile.inc getconf`;
die "Failed to read the configuration: $!" if ($! != 0);
```

As described here at http://www.directadmin.com/forum/showthread.php?t=43558&page=1 I am trying to find the equivalent apt-get install commands for the current version of Debian for:

```
yum install cpan
yum install perl-ExtUtils-CBuilder perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker
cpan install ExtUtils::Install
```

I am trying to find the equivelant Debian solution but unsure which packages to download or install. What would be the exact apt-get install commands needed to properly make this within Debain?

These Perl packages don't appear in Debian as you would expect Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `$!` before checking if it contains something useful. Here's what the code should be:

```
die("Failed to read the configuration: " . (
   $? < 0    ? "Unable to launch: $!" :
   $? & 0x7F ? "Signal ".($? & 0x7F) :
   $? >> 8   ? "Exit ".($? >> 8) :
   "Unknown error"
)) if $?;
```